# Push notification not working with HTTPS

Tags: iphone, https, push-notification

I have used push notification for my project & was working fine with HTTP connection. Server was responding well. Now Its not working with HTTPs . Please guide if any one figure it out. What's the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a self-signed certificate, as far as I'm aware.

From the [developer guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1):

> For each interface you should use TLS (or SSL) to establish a secured
>   communications channel. The SSL certificate required for these 
>   connections is provisioned through the iPhone Developer Program 
>   portal. (See ["Provisioning and Development"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) for details.) To establish 
>   a trusted provider identity, you should present this certificate 
>   to APNs at connection time using peer-to-peer authentication.